# Display image in picture box from datagridview_selectionchanged event

Tags: c#, image, datagridview, picturebox

I have a table with a number of columns tied to a datagridview.  I have a picture box on the same page.  One of the columns in the table is "Photo" and houses the file path of the image.  It was stored as a byte array and I had the picture box manually bound to the datasource.  Is there an easy way to populate the picture box with the image associated from a selected row in the daragridview by reading the cell with the path?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Figured it out.  I moved the code to populate the picture box based off what is selected in the datagridview to a cellClick event.  It worked PERFECTLY.  Code:

```
   private void firearmView_CellClick(object sender, DataGridViewCellEventArgs e)
    {
        if (!firearmView.Rows[e.RowIndex].IsNewRow)
        {
            selectedFirearmPictureBox.Image = Image.FromFile(firearmView.Rows[e.RowIndex].Cells[12].Value.ToString(), true);
        }
    }
```